# Fullcalendar V4 refetch events for all users

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use fullcalendar V4 and I have several users at the same time and I want that when one user refetches events with the command: `calendar.refetchEvents ();`, to refer to users who are currently viewing the calendar.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not without you building some extra functionality to support it (perhaps using websockets or server sent events, to transmit a signal to every browser that it's time to refetch events. Be careful that those triggered refetches don't then trigger another refetch, causing an infinite loop).

Comment: Which framework do you use in the Backend?

Comment: Atheesh Thirumalairajan, i use core PHP...

Comment: ADyson, I tried setInterval (function () {}) and Ajax php Query, and it worked, but it completely blocked MySQL. I'm looking for some waiting function that will be able to wait for a record in the database.

Comment: There's no such thing in MySQL, and anyway it doesn't make sense - refetchEvents doesn't cause an update to the database, so you don't need to (and can't) monitor for that via SQL. Like I alluded to, your PHP needs to record when its endpoint is requested to fetch events, and then send a signal to other browsers (via websockets or SSE) that they should do the same. AJAX polling will kill your PHP server (but it should not touch MySQL) so it's still a bad idea.

Comment: But...thinking about it, the whole thing doesn't even make sense. If one browser fetches new events, why does that mean the others also have to? Are you really talking about a situation where one user **updates** an event (or perhaps creates or deletes one)? It would make a lot more sense to notify the other users when that happens. Even so, you still can't do that via MySQL, it needs to be done via the PHP which processes the update request. You should perhaps consider using websockets for all the I/O to/from the browsers.

Comment: thanks for the answers and reflections. The whole thing makes sense because these are users who work from home and schedule appointments and it is very important that they know when which appointment is busy. Each of them can manually refresh the page and everything will be ok, but the better solution is not to have to worry about refreshing. I keep looking for solutions.

Comment: Yes, auto-refesh is fine, you could just use a setInterval in JS for that, to run refetchEvents every few minutes. That can be done without needing to know what other users are doing. However, my point was that knowing when someone else has refreshed their own calendar it isn't useful. Knowing that someone else has **updated the data** might be useful - but that isn't what you asked about. I was wanting you to clarify if that's what you actually meant, but your comment hasn't really answered my question.

Comment: My basic idea was to use some wait function to detect when a term is entered in the table and then reset the view for each user. That's what I wanted to incorporate into every user script. It hasn't worked as a Setinterval function yet, but I'm still working ...

Comment: setInterval just sets a regular timer. It should be easy to set up. Post the code if you can't get it working, and any error messages.